# Dynamic import, class not found

Tags: php, dynamic, import

I'm trying to make dynamic class instanciation but I'm struggling with that, where does my error(s) come from ?

```php
namespace src\dir;


class Thing {


    public function __construct()
    {
        $files = glob('Check*.php');

        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $this->services[] = pathinfo($file)['filename'];
        }
    }

    public function doThings()
    {
        $i = 0;


        do {
            var_dump(__NAMESPACE__);

            $service = '\\' . __NAMESPACE__ . '\\' .  $this->services[$i];

            $instance = new $service($this->services);

        } while (array_key_exists($i, $this->services));
    }

}
```

Don't mind the do while instead of a foreach :)
I've tried with / without namespaces, with / without namespaces in declaration... :/

Edit :

> string(43) "Class '\src\dir\Truc' not found"

ty

Comment: Well you haven't told us what the error is, but you might start with changing this to a backslash: `namespace src/dir;`

Comment: Not even sure it would have been accepted by php, but in the original code there is a \ , sorry. Added part of the error